# How to change the speed of vertical scrollbar in ListBox in c# .NET winform application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I want to slow the vertical scroll speed in my application. But can't find a way to do it. I found that `VerticalScrollbar.SmallChange` property can be used to control speed. But I can't find that property in the listBox property list. There is HorizontalScrollbar, which I can show or hide. But there is no VerticalScrollbar option. The vertical scrollbar is built-in in list box but apparently no way to control its properties. Any way out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My assumption is that this speed is set using some option at the Windows OS level similar to how fast the mouse cursor should move. I also think controlling this at the app level is not ideal and this is why the framework is hiding it. Pretty sure there is a way to do it but off the top of my head I don't know.

Comment: If there is a way it would help me a lot. I have noticed that the speed varies between applications. For example, In Evernote, the speed is slow. It creates less strain on the eyes. On the other hand in Thunderbird, the speed is high, and I find it a bit strainful for my eyes.